# Angular - change text of label dynamically

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ng-if

**QUESTION:**
how can I change the text of a label depending on a condition?
In my case I want to have a blank label if I am on a specific route in my App.

**CURRENT ATTEMPT:**

```
<RadSideDrawer allowEdgeSwipe="false">
    <StackLayout tkDrawerContent class="drawer-container" VerticalOptions=LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand>
        <GridLayout rows="2*,2*,*,*,*,3*,*,*,*,*,4*" columns="*,6*">
            <Label row="0" col="0" class="fa drawerContainerSymbol" text="&#xf00d;" (tap)="onCloseDrawer()"></Label>
            <Label row="1" col="0" class="fa drawerContainerSymbol" text="&#xf053;" *ngIf="!onMonitorlist()" (tap)="onGoBack()"></Label>
            <Label row="2" col="0" class="fa drawerContainerSymbol" text=""></Label>
            ...
        </GridLayout>
    </StackLayout>
    <StackLayout tkMainContent>
        <page-router-outlet></page-router-outlet>
    </StackLayout>
</RadSideDrawer>
```

The code for checking if I am on the specific route:

```
    onMonitorlist(){
        if(this.router.url === '/monitorliste'){
            return true;
        } else{
            return false
        }
    }
```

This was my attempt with `*ngIf` but if I do it like this I get an ugly white label looking like this:
[image: ugly attempt]

If you have a nice solution on how to display text on label dynamically please let me know!
Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using `[ngClass]="{'drawerContainerTransparent': onMonitorlist()===true}"`

```
.drawerContainerTransparent{
        background: rgb(0,204,153);
        background-color: #00CC99;
        color: rgb(0,204,153);
    }
```

I know the button isn't disabled this way, but I disabled the logic of the button, if I am on the route where it should not be useable. So nothing happens when tapping on the invisable button.

Answer (score 0):

You can set text for your label by default. Then when you are on a specific route in your App you can hide that label by *ngIf and function you have written.

```
 <Label *ngIf="onMonitorlist()"> your text </Label>

 onMonitorlist(){
        if(this.router.url === '/monitorliste'){
            return false;
        } else{
            return true
        }
    }
```

Comment: as I said if I do it like this than I will have the ugly white space on the sidedrawer. (as shown in the picture)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use **ngStyle** with your condition instead of **ngIf**.

```
<Label [ngStyle]="{'display': onMonitorlist() ? 'block' : 'none'}"> your text </Label>
```

Comment: same thing happens, that the whole label isn't displayed what leads to a blank part in the sidedrawer.